# Streamlining event code in visual studio

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm pretty new with VB and I was wondering if there was a better way to write the following code. I have 6 buttons across the top of my form that I have changing colors when the mouse enters and leaves them. Though, I couldn't figure out a way to do this without writing separate subs for each button, for each mouse movement. Any thoughts on shrinking this code? Thanks!

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseEnter
    Button1.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave
    Button1.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseEnter
    Button2.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseLeave
    Button2.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.MouseEnter
    Button3.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.MouseLeave
    Button3.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.MouseEnter
    Button4.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.MouseLeave
    Button4.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.MouseEnter
    Button5.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.MouseLeave
    Button5.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.MouseEnter
    Button6.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.MouseLeave
    Button6.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more than one Handles item, like this:

```
Private Sub Button_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
    Button1.MouseEnter, Button2.MouseEnter, Button3.MouseEnter, Button4.MouseEnter, Button5.MouseEnter, Button6.MouseEnter

    Dim bn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    bn.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
    Button1.MouseLeave, Button2.MouseLeave, Button3.MouseLeave, Button4.MouseLeave, Button5.MouseLeave, Button6.MouseLeave

    Dim bn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    bn.BackColor = Color.Black
End Sub
```

Or you can assign the handlers through code, like this:

```
Private Sub Button_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim bn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    bn.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim bn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    bn.BackColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub SetButtonHandlers()
    Dim bns() As Button = {Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6}
    For Each bn In bns
        AddHandler bn.MouseEnter, AddressOf Button_Enter
        AddHandler bn.MouseLeave, AddressOf Button_Leave
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SetButtonHandlers()

End Sub
```

The latter is easier to update if you were to add or remove buttons, or give them useful names, as they are listed in only one place.